# Linq where 'not like' or ! <> equivalent in

Tags: vb.net, linq, inversion

I've got this working :

```
Dim locations = From row In allLocations.AsEnumerable()                  
Where row.Field(Of String)("PartNr") Is Nothing
Select row
```

It gets all the locations where there is no partnumber. 
But i would like to do something like this to get everything except some record(s):

```
Dim locations = From row In allLocations.AsEnumerable()                  
Where row.Field(Of String)("PartNr") Not Like "12345"
Select row
```

Comment: Why can't you do `<> "12345"`?

Comment: If I try that I get all results (so including the 12345)

Comment: i maybe better clarify, i am not really using a number but a regular expression like : "G[A-Z]*" for example

Comment: In that case, @Richard's answer should work.

Comment: It works for the string parts I define, like G in the example but not for the regular expression. example/regex: G[A-Z]*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found a solution for what i was looking for:

```
Dim rgx As New Regex("^G[A-Z]")
Dim alleLocaties = From row In beginQuery.AsEnumerable()
                   Where (Not rgx.IsMatch(row.Field(Of String)("Location"))
```

In this example i get all the locations that do not start with G followed by a letter.

Answer (score 2):

A simple string contains (ie. equivalent to SQL's `like '%substring%'`) can be done with [`String.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.contains.aspx):

```
Dim locations = From row In allLocations.AsEnumerable()                  
               Where not row.Field(Of String)("PartNr").Contains("12345")
               Select row
```

Comment: Sorry i forgot to say it's not really just a string but a regular expression. i just replied it to the original post to so my apologies for forgetting to clarify this in the op.

Comment: @TomParedis You'll need to apply some Google-Fu to looking up what is possible, which will certainly not include anything close to what .NET regular expressions are capable of (read the docs for `LIKE`: it is very limited matching). To directly use the server's `LIKE` operation you'll need to drop down to SQL I expect.

Comment: Ok i'll try to find the solution. Thanks for helping

Comment: If it's in a `DataTable` you may be able to leverage that too by using [`DataTable.Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/det4aw50(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @TomParedis depending on the row counts involved you could get all from the database and apply the regex in .NET (ie. switch from `IQueryable(Of T)` to `IEnumerable(Of T)` where you can use regex.

Comment: the row counts go up to 500.000, how would i go about changing from IQueryable to IEnumerable?

Comment: @TomParedis Use the `AsEnumerable()` function.

Comment: @Richard Thanks for helping me, I found a solution today using regular expressions. I've posted my solution as an answer too so anyone looking to solve this issue will be able to find my solution